How to address the ambiguity of empty output from "git diff"
When I do git diff mybranch -- my/file
and get no output, I often assume it means there are no differences, but often what really happened is I did not specify the filename correctly (usually because I included or left out part of the relative path)
This is really frustrating since it leads me down a wrong path of thinking. Is there a good technique to address this ambiguity from git?

Use a GUI. Use git diff without arguments. Run realpath on my/file. Use if [ -f "my/file" ]; then to test if the path is correct before git (in a script). Or don't typo the filename to begin with.

You'll have to pry my command line from my cold dead hands

I have over 30 years of command line muscle memory myself. GitLens is still a powerful addition. Also, I think you can check echo $? to see the exit code of the git diff. Which is very user friendly. oh-my-zsh will switch color to indicate the exit code was non-zero. There's probably a similar bash plugin.

@ElliottFrisch: The exit code is zero either way. (Also, I think an ideal solution to this problem would cover things that [ -f doesn’t, like trying to diff an ignored file.)
